# Search icon on soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an ActionLayout for a searchIcon of the MenuItems. This ActionLayout has an AutoCompleteTextView which has `imeOption = "actionSearch"`.

But when i click the menuItems and ActionLayout appears, the soft keyboard pops up, but it still has newline key instead of searchIcon.

**Activity code:**

```
private AutoCompleteTextView mEtSearchbar;
private MenuItem mSearchbar;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 

    case R.id.searchIcon:

        mEtSearchbar.clearFocus();
        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
                mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                        0, 0, 0));
            }
        }, 100);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.m_menu, menu);


    mSearchbar = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.searchIcon);
    View actionview = mSearchbar.getActionView();
    mEtSearchbar = ((AutoCompleteTextView) actionview
            .findViewById(R.id.search_editText));
    final ImageView searchImage = ((ImageView) actionview
            .findViewById(R.id.search_image));
    searchImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String s = mEtSearchbar.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(),
                        SearchActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("search_string", s);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mEtSearchbar
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

                        searchImage.performClick();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

*menu layou*t

**m_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchIcon"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_icon_actionview"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="Notifications"/>

</menu>
```

**search_icon_actionview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="Search icon"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_image"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to have a **searchIcon** or atleast a **done button** on the soft keyboard, which on click must perform the click of the **searcIcon** i have in **ActionLayout**

Thank You

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have to add

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

also